# c# MVC recieving json array in controllor from angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing a shopping website and I have a Product model:

```
private string _catalog;
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{4}$",ErrorMessage="Catalog number must contain 4 digits")]
    public string Catalog
    {
        get
        {
            return _catalog;
        }
        set
        {
            _catalog = value.ToString();
        }
    }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
```

And I defined in AngularJS a json array

```
$scope.Cart=[{}];
```

and adding items to the cart by

```
$scope.Cart.push(...);
```

Now I have my post command:

```
$http({ method: "POST", data: $scope.Cart, url: "Buy" })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.lock = false;
            });
```

And the action is:

```
public ActionResult Buy(List<Product> pr){
     return Content("Buy");
}
```

but the pr List is null.

how do i fix it?

Comment: What's the exact payload of the AJAX request? You can see it in the `Network` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I tried to use the angular.toJson() and still it was null, but then I removed the 0 element which was always empty, and sent it to the post, finally works.

```
            $scope.Cart.splice(0, 1);
            var param = angular.toJson($scope.Cart);
            $http({ method: "POST", data: param, url: "Buy" })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.lock = false;
            });
```